# actionscript 3 TextField visible characters indexes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm implementing a scrollbar for my non editable *textField*, and i have to enable pageup, pagedown, end, mousewheel as well. everything works, except wheel sometimes. **I'd need to get the first visible characters index** to make sure that the keyboard 'cursor' is updated via  *setselection* . 
I tried with scrollV, but thats sometimes not ok.

**update**: Added code. Note: I've played a lot, and this is a semi-working solution.

on scrollbar scroll:

```
_TextField.scrollV = pValue*_TextField.maxScrollV
```

on keyboard:

```
 if( pEvent.keyCode==Keyboard.UP ) {
            _TextField.scrollV--
        }
        if( pEvent.keyCode==Keyboard.DOWN ) {
            _TextField.scrollV++
        }
        if( pEvent.keyCode==Keyboard.END ) {
            _TextField.setSelection(_TextField.length,_TextField.length)
            _TextField.scrollV = _TextField.maxScrollV;
        }
        if( pEvent.keyCode==Keyboard.HOME ) {
            _TextField.setSelection(0,0)workaround 
            _TextField.scrollV = 1;
        }
        setTimeout(scrollBarUpdate, 0, 0);
```

on wheel:

_TextField.scrollV -= pEvent.delta;

```
        var firstShownLine:int = _TextField.getLineIndexAtPoint(10,10)
        if( firstShownLine != -1 ){
            if(stage.focus == _TextField){
                var currentIndex:int =  _TextField.getLineOffset(firstShownLine);
                var offsetUp:int    =   _TextField.getLineLength(_TextField.scrollV) * 2 + 2; 
                var offsetDown:int  =   _TextField.getLineLength(_TextField.scrollV - 1) * 2 + 2; 
                if(pEvent.delta>0){
                    _TextField.setSelection(currentIndex-offsetUp,currentIndex-offsetUp);
                }
                else{
                    _TextField.setSelection(currentIndex+offsetDown,currentIndex+offsetDown); 
                }
            }
        }

        scrollBarUpdate();
```

Comment: Can you post some code ? I don't see the link between the mousewheel and the cursor / setselection ?...

Comment: posted.. the onWheel function is newer. Now it is nearly 100% functional.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I still cannot understand what you're trying to do here. You're making a scrollbar and trying to scroll a TextField, that I understand. But what is the link with the textfield selection ? _Are you trying be able to scroll inside your textfield but always show the selected text ? Are you trying to select the visible part of the textfield ?_ **Please explain exactly what is your goal**, because if its only to scroll the textfield, you're over-complicating the whole problem.

Comment: My goal is to allow users to use PageUp and PageDown as well for navigation. the selected text is 0 length, so its just where the cursor would stand.